# Grab last iteration of a specific list in Python -- and only last specific item

Tags: python, list, if-statement

How do I grab that last iteration of a specific item in a python list that matches my `if` statement?

for example:

```
my_list = ["passed1", "passed2", "passed3", "vetoed"]
my_other_list = ["passed4", "passed5", "passed6", "vetoed"]

combo_list = []
combo_list.append(my_list)
combo_list.append(my_other_list)

desired_output_list = []
```

How do I grab the final iteration of "passed" and ONLY the final iteration of passed?

```
for x in combo_list:
    ###Grab passed3 and passed6 and append to desired_output_list
```

Comment: `if "passed" == list[-1]`? Also do not name your variable `list` as you will shadow the built-in type

Comment: First, never use ```list``` keyword as a variable. And what do you mean by *How do I grab the final iteration of "passed" and ONLY the final iteration of passed?*. You can use ```list[:-1]```

Comment: Lists don't have iterations.

Comment: `combo_list` doesn't preserve the distinction between `my_list` and `my_other_list`; for all you know, the original lists could have been `[]` and `["passed1", "passed2", ..., "vetoed"]`, which would appear to change your expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Use the last item from a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) and append it to the desired output list:

```
my_list = ["passed1", "passed2", "passed3", "vetoed"]
my_other_list = ["passed4", "passed5", "passed6", "vetoed"]

combo_list = []
combo_list.append(my_list)
combo_list.append(my_other_list)

desired_output_list = []
for lst in combo_list:
    matches = [item for item in lst if "passed" in item]
    if matches:
        desired_output_list.append(matches[-1])

print(desired_output_list)
# ['passed3', 'passed6']
```